# Which hosting controller should I install in a dedicated server, that can handle PHP 5.3?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, hosting, dedicated-server

Hey everyone, I'm new to server administration, so I'm just trying to find a good hosting controller that let me do/have these things in my new dedicated server:
- Create hosting accounts, each one with its own bandwidth/storage limits.
- PHP 5.3
- MySQL

Someone told me to install CentOS and Klox, but from what I read, klox does not support PHP 5.3. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

CentOS 5 (and I guess Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 too) doesn't have great support for PHP 5.3, at least in it absence of it in the official yum repos.  Latest version available there is 5.1.6 which is pretty old...

If you are just starting out on this path, and require PHP 5.3 you might want to use another distro that does officially support PHP 5.3.  Ubuntu Server 10.10 has PHP 5.3 in its official apt packages.